# MySQL not release memory

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I'm using MySQL on big enough project. and sone of scripts use to much  memory.
I'm trying to know why. but the main problem that mysql do not release it.

mysql stands on separate server. on charts it looks like
http://o7.no/wMobCB
now it start using it more, then in ~20 hours mysql server will be restarted by watchdog (i guess because it's not enough memory).

Usually it takes lesse memory but after some script is running it takes more and more...

what can be reason of so strange behavior ?

Comment: "after some script is running it takes more and more." what is this script doing?

Comment: Most database servers will use as much memory as they can possibly get their fingers on, because it improves performance. This is most likely simply part of its normal modus operandi. Do you have any indication that it *shouldn't* behave this way?

Comment: Without getting into detail about your script, can you log slow queries and find the problematic ones?

Comment: @deceze In day hours memory usage is normal, and i have a lot of visitors. but at night i have a lot of crons, now i'm investigating which one is make this loading, but nothing in slow-queries.log :(
http://o7.no/zr79Ed You see it's every time growing and then restarting :(

Answer (score 0):

If the watchdog kicks in and kills MySQL, then something is wrong. Make sure that your memory settings in my.ini isn't way of.

I have also experienced that this issue might occur if you have corrupted tables, where a query would actually run for so long that it would die because the daemon gets restarted. However, it has always been related to a query that has been running. Use mytop or similiar and try to identify if that is the case.

Comment: I have slow log and from 2 till 4 i see there only 2 sql queries (long_query_time=10)
`# Time: 120306  2:21:46
# Query_time: 15.133891  Lock_time: 0.000097 Rows_sent: 372  Rows_examined: 372
SET timestamp=1330993306;
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `db` LIKE '%';
# Time: 120306  2:22:11
# Query_time: 12.601633  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 423  Rows_examined: 423
SET timestamp=1330993331;
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `db` LIKE '%';`
so in slow log nothing more between 2 and 4am. but memory become growing from 2 till 4am. How these queries can do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure that the slow_log actually manage to log a query that forces your mysql server to crash. Because it probably do it when the server has finished execution (to log the actual time it took). You could make a cron job that takes a snapshot of currently running queries every 5 minutes and pot it in a log file.